# Need to pass variable from one glue job to another via event bridge using stepfunction

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

What is the correct way to pass the parameter from the glue job to another via event bridge trigger in stepfunction?

The format of stepfunction is

```
{
"comment":"This is a step function",
"startat":"parallel",
"states":{
"Type":"parallel",
"ResultsPath":"$.parallelResults",
"Branches":[
{
"startAt":"Glue Job start servicenow table incident",
"states":{
"type":"Task",
"Resource":"arn:aws:states:::gluejob:startJobRun.sync",
"Parameters":{
"Jobname":"glue job name",
"Arguments":{
      "--market.$":"$.market",
      "--dates.$":"$.dates",
}
},
"End":True

}
}
#----runs for other table in parallel  ----
]

},
"Eventbridge PutEvent":{
"type":"Task",
"Resource":"arn:aws:states:::gluejob:startJobRun.sync",
"Parameters":{
"Entries":{
"Details" :{"My Message":"{\"market\":null,\"dates:" **Need to pass dates form arguments from above parallel job into the event bridge job** "}
}
}

}
```

Here I need to pass the dates into the details message so the eventbridge will trigger the sns with this message

dates contains a dictonary in string format
Ex:
dates:"{"to_date":"2024-01-02 00:00:00","from_date":"2024-01-01 00:00:00"}"
this need to be passed to details in message to other glue job.

how can it be passed?

Tried using the`$.parallelresults[0].output.arguments[--dates]`  but it is not working

We are getting the parameter as None in the next glue job trigger